# Spring Boot Admin: custom header authentication

Tags: spring-boot-admin

My app has a custom authentication mechanism based on a custom HTTP header. AFAIK, Spring Boot Admin supports only Basic auth and OAuth. But maybe there's a way for clients to supply some custom header along with their requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so if both SBA Server and SBA Client are launched along with the monitored application itself, and it has custom-headers security, we need to take care of 3 things:

1. As Nitin mentioned, one needs to register `HttpHeadersProvider` bean:

```java
    @Bean
    public HttpHeadersProvider customHttpHeadersProvider() {
        return instance -> {
            HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            httpHeaders.add("X-CUSTOM", "My Custom Value");
            return httpHeaders;
        };
    }
```

2. Note, that these headers are not applied to `OPTIONS` requests to the Actuator endpoints, so one would either need to customize `ProbeEndpointsStrategy`, or disable Spring Security for `OPTIONS` calls to the management URL. Also, for some reason, I had to disable security for `/actuator/health/**`, although it should've been accessible with custom header provided:

```java
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/actuator/**").antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/actuator/health/**");
    }
```

3. Finally, one needs to instantiate `ApplicationRegistrator` with a custom `RestTemplate` that would be pre-populated with a custom header:

```java
    @Bean
    public ApplicationRegistrator registrator(ClientProperties client, ApplicationFactory applicationFactory) {
        RestTemplateBuilder builder = new RestTemplateBuilder()
                .setConnectTimeout(client.getConnectTimeout())
                .setReadTimeout(client.getReadTimeout())
                .additionalInterceptors((request, body, execution) -> {
                    request.getHeaders().set("X-CUSTOM", "My Custom Value");
                    return execution.execute(request, body);
                });
        if (client.getUsername() != null) {
            builder = builder.basicAuthentication(client.getUsername(), client.getPassword());
        }
        return new ApplicationRegistrator(builder.build(), client, applicationFactory);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the custom headers into existing headers by injecting the Bean as following.

```
@Bean
public HttpHeadersProvider customHttpHeadersProvider() {
    return instance -> {
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.add("X-CUSTOM", "My Custom Value");
        return httpHeaders;
    };
}
```

Comment: This didn't work. I have declared this bean with my header, but this header didn't get to `de.codecentric.boot.admin.client.registration.ApplicationRegistrator`. In fact, I looked into `ApplicationRegistrator` code and I couldn't find any places where this bean would be used.